# Issue with getting init parameters

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```
out.println("<br>" + getServletConfig().getInitParameter("ad"));
out.print("<br>" + getServletContext().getInitParameter("email"));
```

I have a JSP page.

When I run my app it always returns null, instead of email.

But when I use it in my servlet code it runs fine.

Here is the complete Code:

```
<% 
List styless = (List) request.getAttribute("styles");
int n = styless.size();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    out.print("<br>" + styless.get(i));
}
out.println("<br>" + getServletConfig().getInitParameter("ad"));
out.print("<br>" + getServletContext().getInitParameter("email"));
%>
```

In this code neither ServletConfig or ServletContext is working both returning null,but same thing working good in servlet

web.xml

```
<servlet> 
    <servlet-name>Ch3 Beer</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>action.BeerSelect</servlet-class> 
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>ad</param-name> 
        <param-value>hawc91@gmail.com</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
</servlet>
<context-param> 
    <param-name>email</param-name> 
    <param-value>rnsal28@yahoo.com</param-value> 
</context-param>
```

Comment: code is:   <%
List styless=(List)request.getAttribute("styles");

int n=styless.size();
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
 out.print("<br>"+styless.get(i));
 }
out.println("<br>" + getServletConfig().getInitParameter("ad"));
out.print("<br>" + getServletContext().getInitParameter("email"));
%>   in this code neither ServletConfig or ServletContext is working both returning null,but same thing working good in servlet

Comment: Without knowing how you're actually *setting* the parameter it's impossible to answer. Is it an init param, or a context param?

Comment: You must post a valid [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so people can understand your problem and help you or learn from it.

Comment: in my web.xml i have set:  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Ch3 Beer</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>action.BeerSelect</servlet-class>
  
  <init-param>
  <param-name>ad</param-name>
  <param-value>hawc91@gmail.com</param-value>
  </init-param>
  
  </servlet><context-param>
  <param-name>email</param-name>
  <param-value>rnsal28@yahoo.com</param-value>
  </context-param>

Comment: is there some site where i can scrible my problem in details with code

Comment: @user2556835 HERE. In your question. Don't add complex code/config in comments, it's illegible--edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

As the code is described in your question, the `email` parameter should display both in JSP and Servlet (and it does, I tested it) using the code `getServletContext().getInitParameter("email")`.

Now the `ad` parameter, it displays `null` (correctly) in the JSP because this parameter in local to the Servlet. The `ad` is only available(and that's what it should be) inside the Servlet code and can be accessed using `getServletConfig().getInitParameter("ad")`

Comment: No , Email parameter returning null in jsp only,,but in servlet it returning email id well...and for ad parameter ,if have use RequestDispatcher as response.setAttribute("style",li); then Requestdispatcher view=request.getRequestDispacther("result.jsp"); and theh view.forward(response,request);

Answer (score 0):

When you're declaring context parameters like this:

```
<context-param> 
    <param-name>email</param-name> 
    <param-value>rnsal28@yahoo.com</param-value> 
</context-param>
```

Then you need to access it using 'application' object:

```
<% 
    String email=application.getInitParameter("email"); 
    System.out.println(email);
%>
```

Comment: Wow Its work..but wht we have used application.get.....and what about ServletContext